# What is the maximum buffer size of data transformation in ssis?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

I am currently trying to load 189 Mb data from an Excel source. However I am getting the following error :

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.

Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/fd0f0a28-3bb5-489f-8940-fd397443cfb8/ssis-project-error-could-not-retrieve-the-table-information-for-the-connection-manager-excel?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Your error message likely has nothing to do with the size of data you're attempting to process, as Amira references. Prove it to yourself, delete all but the first 10 rows from your Excel file and run your process - you'll see the same error.